# PHP Warning: mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given

Tags: php, mysql

estou tendo este problema. alguem sabe porque? Isto é de um livro de php

[image: Codigo]

Meu log consta isto

[Sun Sep 30 22:56:16.203629 2018] [php7:warn] [pid 31940] [client ::1:53268] PHP Warning:  mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /var/www/html/php-oo/lv-77/mysql_lista.php on line 7, referer: http://localhost/php-oo/lv-77/

[Sun Sep 30 22:56:16.203662 2018] [php7:warn] [pid 31940] [client ::1:53268] PHP Warning:  mysqli_close() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /var/www/html/php-oo/lv-77/mysql_lista.php on line 16, referer: http://localhost/php-oo/lv-77/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Olá,
eu acho que esta tendo problemas com a conexão com o banco de dados, verifique o usuario, senha e se o banco e a tabela foram devidamente criados e também evite dar espaços, tente fazer assim:

$conn = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','mysql','livro');

---- e também verifique se esta colocando os dados de conexão na posição correta, segue um exemplo abaixo:

*** db = Database**

$conn = mysqli_connect('host_do_seu_db','usuario_db','senha_db','nome_db');

Teste e veja se funciona, abçs.

Comment: Era isso. Obrigado vcs 2 pela grande ajuda

Answer (score 1):

Provavelmente o mysqli_connect() está falhando, o que atribui FALSE à variável $conn. Sugiro colocar um teste depois da conexão, algo como

```
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Falhou ao conectar com MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```